# Can the Riemann Zeta derivative be expressed in terms of Riemann Zeta?

Tags: riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

From this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134600/zetax-in-terms-of-zetax-zeta1-x-gamma-psi it seems that Zeta can be expressed through its derivative:

$$\zeta(1-x) = \frac{2(\zeta'(x)\Gamma(x/2)+\Gamma((1-x)/2) \zeta'(1-x)\pi^{x-1/2})  )}{\Gamma((1-x)/2) \pi^{-1/2+x}(2\log\pi -\psi((1-x)/2)-\psi(x/2))}$$

I wonder, if the opposite is possible? Can the Riemann Zeta derivative be expressed in terms of Riemann Zeta?

Answer (score 2):

With $\zeta(s):=\chi(1-s)\,\zeta(1-s), \, \, \chi(s):= \Gamma  \left( s \right) \cos \left(\frac12\pi s \right) 2 \left( 2\pi \right) ^{-s}$

the formula above can be simplified into:

$$\zeta(s):= -\dfrac{\zeta'(1-s)+\chi(s)\,\zeta'(s)}{\chi'(s)}$$

*** begin addition ***

There actually is a way to express $\zeta'(s)$ in terms of $\zeta(s)$ through the following formula:

$$\zeta'(s)= -\zeta(s)\cdot\big(\gamma + \Psi^{(0)}(1-s)\big) +\Psi^{(s-1)}(1)\cdot\Gamma(1-s)$$

with $\Psi^{(x)}(z)$ being the Polygamma function and $\gamma$ the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

However, there is an ugly snag here, since the analytic continuation of $\Psi^{(s-1)}(1)$ to complex and negative-integer values of $s$, is defined in terms of $\zeta'(s)$ and $\zeta(s)$...

*** end addition ***

To give a (very partial) answer to your question, for $s=-2k, k=1,2,3...$ it is known that $\zeta'(s)$ can be expressed in terms of $\zeta(s)$ and a ratio involving $\pi^{2k}$ e.g.:

$\zeta'(-2)= -\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}$

$\zeta'(-4)= \dfrac{3}{4}\dfrac{\zeta(5)}{\pi^4}$

$\zeta'(-6)= -\dfrac{45}{8}\dfrac{\zeta(7)}{\pi^6}$

$\dots$

The other likely candidate is $s=2$ where we have $\zeta'(2)= \zeta(2)\,\big(\gamma + \ln(2\,\pi) - 12\, \ln(A) \big)$ where $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html). However, since $A$ has a closed form in terms of $\zeta'(1)$ that leads to: $\zeta(2)\,\big(\gamma + \ln(2\,\pi) - 1 + 12\, \zeta'(-1) \big)$, I like to disregard this one as a valid solution.

Could not find a more generic expressions for $\zeta'(s)$ and think the key problem is that no functional equation is known that links $\zeta'(s)$ to $\zeta'(1-s)$ that allows eliminating one of them.

Comment: The problem with your addition part is also that polygamma is not defined for non-integer indexes as well.

Comment: Anixx, it actually is defined for all indices in $\mathbb{C}$ of the polygamma. See link here: http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Psi I tested it in a Maple and it works fine. Was surprised to learn a function exists that links $\zeta(s)$ to its derivative. Through the functional equation you can then also link $\zeta'(s)$ and $\zeta'(1-s)$. However $\Psi^{s}(1)$ is defined in terms of $\zeta(s)$, so we won't gain much.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for the derivative expression?

Comment: giordano, please check the following link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206198/are-all-complex-zeros-of-dfrac-zeta-zetas-pm-dfrac-zeta-zeta1-s It contains a reference to Apostol's paper from the derivative expression is easy to derive.

Comment: What is the general gormula for these equalities for negative $s$? Does it come from the polygamma formula?

Comment: Using your first formula (from addition) with $s=-2$, I get $\frac{1}{2} \log \left(2 \pi  A^4\right)$, which is not what your other formula gives, $\zeta'(-2)= -\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}$

Comment: @Anixx, I've tried it in Maple and it works fine. You are referring to this formula $\zeta'(s)= -\zeta(s)\cdot\big(\gamma + \Psi^{(0)}(1-s)\big) +\Psi^{(s-1)}(1)\cdot\Gamma(1-s)$, right? The first term is $0$ due to $\zeta(-2)=0$. The fractional differentiation of $\Psi^{(-2-1)} = -\frac{\zeta(3)}{8\pi^2}$ and multiplied by $\Gamma(3) = 2$ gives the desired result.

Comment: @Agno Well, Mathematica evaluates PolyGamma with negative index differently: http://tinyurl.com/42wxzs8t

Comment: "However, there is an ugly snag here, since the analytic continuation of Ψ(s−1)(1) to complex and negative-integer values of s, is defined in terms of ζ′(s) and ζ(s)... " - do you have a link?

Comment: @Anixx See the last bullet under Description of this link: https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Psi Although this question is pretty old,  this was the place I got the equation from. If I recall correctly, it was the balanced polygamma formula of Espinosa and Moll that is expressed in $\zeta'(s)$ and $\zeta(s)$, so nothing new would be gained. The first to express the fractional derivative of $\zeta(s)$ in terms of $\Psi$ for $\Re(s) > 1$ was JB Keiper. See this deck: https://aims-cameroon.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2021/03/ACRCC-AF-Fractional-zeta-slides.pdf

Comment: @Agno Ah, I see. Formerly I was a big fan of the formula by Espinosa and Moll, but later changed my mind. Anyway, it is not the usual generalization of PolyGamma. I even wonder whether I with my posts on StackExchange of the time popularizing the formula contributed to Maple's adoption of this formula for their generalization.